# I created my shell script and I am trying to access data in NAS Mount directory. When I tried to execute the script I get the following error

Tags: unix

Script as -

## /bin/bash

1 START_TIME=($date +%s)
echo "calling enviroment variable"

and when i tried to run tho above script i got

error as
calling enviroment variable
/bin/bash 22-1-2016 line 1 : command not found

Comment: Please edit your question to better reflect the command you are running. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

You should start your script with a she-bang ([source](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html)) therefore :

```
/bin/bash
```

should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```